# Exploding indexes and unix timestamp

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Each of my entities consist of a number of single-value properties and one array.

In each entity there is a unix epoch timestamp and a user id.

My problem is I'd like to be able to do this kind of query

`SELECT * FROM <kind> WHERE time >= value AND time <= value and userId = value`

The issue is I have to create a composite index but I've also read about exploding indexes and storage space but I cannot quite understand it.

Can someone please explain to me if creating such composite index is it an "exploding index" and if the query is good or not.

Answer (score 5):

The exploding indexes problem (and the associated storage usage growth) is only applicable when multi-value (array/repeated) properties are included in the index. Since your particular query only refers to single-value properties (`time` and `userId`) the corresponding index won't be an exploding one.

But you may have a potential problem you need to consider: the monotonic `time` property can cause trouble at high read/write rates. From [Indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#indexes):

> - Do not index properties with monotonically increasing values (such as a NOW() timestamp). Maintaining such an index could lead to
>     hotspots that impact Cloud Datastore latency for applications with
>     high read and write rates. For further guidance on dealing with
>     monotonic properties, see [High read/write rates for a narrow key
>     range](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#high_readwrite_rates_to_a_narrow_key_range) below.

And

> Likewise, if you need to query on a monotonically increasing (or
>   decreasing) property using a sort or filter, you could instead index
>   on a new property, for which you prefix the monotonic value with a
>   value that has high cardinality across the dataset, but is common to
>   all the entities in the scope of the query you want to perform. For
>   instance, if you want to query for entries by timestamp but only need
>   to return results for a single user at a time, you could prefix the
>   timestamp with the user id and index that new property instead. This
>   would still permit queries and ordered results for that user, but the
>   presence of the user id would ensure the index itself is well sharded.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have a few follow-up questions. 1. Each entry has an array with multiple different phone numbers and as you said the composite index is only exploding if the array is part of the composite index. Is the array on its own with two regular indexes exploding? 2. The amount of phone numbers is different, from 1 to 100 will the array cause the same slowdown because they're numbers? 3. Regarding monotonically values. So I just prepend the timestamp like this userIdString_timestamp. That should fix the bottleneck and still allow for less/greater/equal operators?

Comment: I don't think I understand #1, please clarify. For #2 it's the number of possible values that makes the index potentially exploding, not the fact that the values are numbers - the same would happen if they'd be strings for example. Also - the exploding indexes don't cause read/write showdowns, they can only cause longer eventual consistency durations and storage increases. Yes, that timestamping solution should address those issues.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear. About #1, each entry has a property which is an array with phone numbers and it varies how many numbers from 1 to 100. If this property is not within a composite index but just its own normal index, is this array causing exploding index? Another question: since the array contains phone numbers in either string or number type will that array potentially cause a hotspot at high read/write?

Comment: For #1 - no, that simple index for the array property won't be an exploding one. The phone numbers could theoretically raise the hotspot issue, but really - what are the chances of that actually happening in real life? Maybe during testing, while you pre-populate the datastore in batch mode with a pile of entries. I wouldn't worry too much about it. If you do - you can always apply the same technique as for the timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Exploding index isn't just a composite index issue. When you create a composite index, you are creating just another index for a set of attributes instead of just one. Normally, you would only be storing one copy of your data unless one or more attributes in the entity is a repeated/nested field. [Exploding index](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#index_limits) is when you erroneously index every attribute of your entity for giggles and not realizing that if you have a REPEATED or NESTED field, you are indexing it multiple times.

Example: If you save this Entity kind with 3 String attributes:

Name & Hobbies & Favorite Color. Even if you index every attribute, you are at most storing 3 tables sorted by each attribute, no big deal.

However, if hobbies and favorite color were stored as repeated or nested fields, now you have 6 hobbies and 7 colors... Now every row is stored 6*7=42 times! That's what you need to avoid. If a nested field does not need to be queried and sorted against, don't index it.