# Index timestamp in Google Datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

My previous question: [Errors saving data to Google Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277097/errors-saving-data-to-google-datastore)

We're running into issues writing to Datastore. Based on the previous question, we think the issue is that we're indexing a "SeenTime" attribute with YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ (e.g. 2021-04-29T17:42:58Z) and this is creating a hotspot (see: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#indexes).

We need to index this because we're querying the data by date and need the time for each observation in the end application. Is there a way around this issue where we can still query by date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exploding indexes and unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643902/exploding-indexes-and-unix-timestamp)

Comment: In addition, if you do have a key or indexed property that will be monotonically increasing then you can prepend a random hash to ensure that the keys are sharded onto multiple tablets. These are all documented in GCP.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your first link, apologies--I'm pretty new to this. If we prepend a random hash to the monotonically increasing timestamp index, how can we query it later? The query we use is: `QUERY = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE seenTime >= '{}' AND seenTime <= '{}'".format(day_before_start, day_before_end)` in our flask app and there doesn't seem to be a way to substring out the hash during a query.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit late but:

1. On your previous question, before even writing a query, it feels like the main issue is "running into issues writing" (DEADLINE_EXCEEDED/UNAVAILABLE) -> it's happening on "some saves" -- so, it's not completely clear if it's due to data hot-spotting or from "ingesting more data in shorter bursts", which causes contention (see ["Designing for scale"](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#designing_for_scale)).

> A single entity in Datastore mode should not be updated too rapidly. If you are using Datastore mode, design your application so that it will not need to update an entity more than once per second. If you update an entity too rapidly, then your Datastore mode writes will have higher latency, timeouts, and other types of error. This is known as contention.

2. You would need to add a prefix to the key to index monotonically increasing timestamps (as mentioned in the best-practices doc). Then you can [test your queries using GQL interface](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/quickstart#run_gql_queries) in the console. However, since you most likely want "all events", I don't think it would be possible, and so will result in hot-spotting & read-latency.
3. The impression is that the latency might be unavoidable. If so, then you would need to decide if it's acceptable, depending on the frequency of your query/number-of-elements returned, along with the amount of latency (performance impact).
4. Consider switching to Firestore Native Mode. It has a different architecture under the hood and is the next version of Datastore. While Firestore is not perfect, it [can be more forgiving](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#soft_limits) about hot-spotting and contention, so it's possible that you'll have fewer issues than in Datastore.